# Style: Ending code blocks with `pass` vs `return`/`continue` vs nothing

Tags: python, pep8

The `pass` statement in python does nothing except fill space. However, I've found it useful for designating the end of a long, complicated block of code, before the program continues:

```
...
if condition is True:
    ...
    pass
...
```

essentially, the same effect as putting the `}` on its own line would have, in a language like C or Java.

Similarly, I've developed the habit of replacing `pass` with `continue` at the end of loops, or `return` at the end of functions that wouldn't otherwise return anything, for the same reason - and to make it more clear which block of code is ending:

```
def someFunc():
    ...
    while someCondition is True:
        # complicated things
        ...
        continue
    ...
    return
```

When code is spaced either very narrowly or very widely, or when the code takes up a lot of vertical space, I think that putting these statements at the end of a code block makes the control flow clearer. I've done some searching, and haven't found a good source that said whether this is good or bad style (making good search keywords for this subject is annoyingly difficult). Moreover, PEP8 says nothing on the matter. I was hoping to get opinions on the subject and find what the general consensus is, if there is one.

Comment: I vote that this is primarily opinion and no good will come from debating it here.

Comment: Some editors (e.g. sumblime) have vertical line in the indentation that will show the scope of a block

Comment: This really does detract from my understanding of what each loop is doing. If there is no guidance then this perhaps falls to opinion, and I find it confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### From "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin -

> The first rule of functions is that they should be **small**.
>
> The second rule of functions is that they should be **smaller than that**.

#### From [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) -

> Simple is better than complex.
>
> Readability counts.

When writing code, in any language, you are supposed to write small pieces of code (method, loop, if, etc.) that will be easy to read and understand.
By following this rule, you won't end up with *long, complicated block of code* as you mentioned, and as a result the need for any `pass`, `continue` or `return` will be gone.

#### Bottom line

If you got to the point where you want to add these statements - **refactor your code**